# Embedding COM components into an AIR app?

Tags: com, air

If you didn't care about cross platform deployment, is it possible to embed a COM component into an AIR app?

Googling shows nothing on this.

A link to an example of how to do it would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

No, from what I have seen, AIR 1.5 does not support COM Interop out-of-the-box.